# How can I create a shortcut to a shared file through OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive

I have a file that I created and shared with my coworker via OneDrive but he wants to have a shortcut on his desktop that allows him to open the file in the desktop Excel app just by clicking on that shortcut.

Does anyone know the correct steps to make this happen?

Comment: If your associate has permission to the folder, the associate can use NET USE Z: \\sharedfolder\file to access the file.

Comment: Sync to local? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-files-with-onedrive-in-windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49

Answer (score 1):

Piece of cake.

1. Copy the shared link as generated by OneDrive web-view.
   [image: Cool Stufferz]
2. Right click the desktop -> New Shortcut
3. Under "Type the location of the item", paste in the url/link.
4. Under "Type a name for this shortcut", put "Bob".. it must be Bob.. or whatever you want to call it.

If you want to use the rich client for excel (as in not the browser version), it is just a little more involved.  You will need to:

1. Create a shortcut to excel.
2. Right click the shortcut and pull up properties
3. In the "Target" field, AFTER "Excel.exe", paste in the URL to your document.
4. Change the icon to avoid confusion
5. Rename the shortcut to "Bob".